# How to implement IComparable to custom type?

Tags: c#, wpf

First of all, sorry if the question is a bit long, but I need to explain all the details to provide a verifiable example.

**Summary of the Problem**

In my application I use an extension class of `ObservableCollection` called `AsyncObservableCollection`, this class allow me to add items to a collection across multiple threads.

All working well, but there is a problem that happen when I use the sorting on the `CollectionViewSource`, infact seems that I need to implement on the object of the collection the `IComparable` interface for avoid this exception:

> Cannot compare two element in the array

This error happen only the second time that I add items to the collection, for the first valorization all working well.

**Code Structure**

First of all, I need to show you the `AsyncObservableCollection`, this class have the following implementation:

```
public class AsyncObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private readonly SynchronizationContext _synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    public AsyncObservableCollection()
    {
    }

    public AsyncObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> list)
        : base(list)
    {
    }

    private void ExecuteOnSyncContext(Action action)
    {
        if (SynchronizationContext.Current == _synchronizationContext)
        {
            action();
        }
        else
        {
            _synchronizationContext.Send(_ => action(), null);
        }
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        ExecuteOnSyncContext(() => base.InsertItem(index, item));
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        ExecuteOnSyncContext(() => base.RemoveItem(index));
    }

    protected override void SetItem(int index, T item)
    {
        ExecuteOnSyncContext(() => base.SetItem(index, item));
    }

    protected override void MoveItem(int oldIndex, int newIndex)
    {
        ExecuteOnSyncContext(() => base.MoveItem(oldIndex, newIndex));
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        ExecuteOnSyncContext(() => base.ClearItems());
    }

    public void RemoveAll(Predicate<T> predicate)
    {
        //Controllo se l'insieme viene modificato
        CheckReentrancy();

        List<T> itemsToRemove = Items.Where(x => predicate(x)).ToList();
        itemsToRemove.ForEach(item => Items.Remove(item));

        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
}
```

in this `AsyncObservableCollection` I need to pass also a custom type called `CheckedListItem`, this class allow me to add in my `ComboBox`, for each `Item`, a `CheckBox` with the `Item Name`. Like [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31105/A-ComboBox-with-a-CheckedListBox-as-a-Dropdown) for example.

The implementation of `CheckedListItem` is this:

```
public class CheckedListItem<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool isChecked;
    private T item;

    public CheckedListItem() { }

    public CheckedListItem(T item, bool isChecked = false)
    {
        this.item = item;
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
    }

    public T Item
    {
        get { return item; }
        set
        {
            item = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item"));
        }
    }

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return isChecked; }
        set
        {
            isChecked = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsChecked"));
        }
    }
}
```

in the `ComboBox` I've as `AsyncObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<T>>` a list of `Country`, essentially the `Country` class is like this:

```
public class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ISO { get; set; }
}
```

each `Country` have an `ISO`, for more details about the `ISO` (it's not important for this question, you could see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1))

**XAML and Collection valorization**

In my code the user can load a specific `Country` to the `AsyncObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Country>>`, this will appear inside a `ComboBox` that is defined in this way:

```
<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedData}}"
           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CombinedTemplate}" />
```

the `GroupedData` bound the `AsyncObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Country>>` sorting for ISO:

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Countries}" x:Key="GroupedData">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Item.ISO" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>

<DataTemplate x:Key="NormalItemTemplate">
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
                  Content="{Binding Item.Name}"                             
                  Checked="Countries_Checked" Unchecked="Countries_Unchecked"/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="CombinedTemplate">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter" 
           Content="{Binding}"
           ContentTemplate="{StaticResource NormalItemTemplate}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

essentially when I add the data to the collection I do something similar to:

```
var ckli = new CheckedListItem<Country>();
    ckli.Item = new Country
    {
       Name = "England", 
       ISO = "EN"
    }

Countries.Add(ckli);
```

where `Countries` is defined in that way:

```
private AsyncObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Country>> _countries = new AsyncObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Country>>();

public AsyncObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Country>> Countries 
{
    get { return _countries; }
    set 
    { 
        _countries = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(); //<- INotifyPropertyChanged of ViewModel
    }
}
```

**The Problem**

as I said, when I add a `Country` for the first time to `Countries`, all working well, but when I execute the same method for adding the `Country` specified by the user, I get the exception above:

> Cannot compare two element in the array

I tried to solve this by implementing `IComparable` interface on `Country` class. So I guess I should implement on the `ISO` property, and I did something similar to:

```
public class Country : IComparer<Country>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ISO { get; set; }

    public int Compare(Country x, Country y)
    {
        if(x.ISO == y.ISO)
           return 0;

        if(x.ISO != y.ISO)
          return -1;

        return 1;
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is a good implementation, I really don't use this interface and still I don't know if I need to implement `IComparer` to the sorted property or for all properties. Anyway, the issue is not solved with my solution, so I hope that someone read this heavy and boring question, to give me an help.

Thanks.

**UPDATE #1**

Following the example suggested, I tried to implement the `IComparable` in this way:

```
public class Country : IComparable<Country>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ISO { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
       return CompareTo(obj as Country);
    }

    public int CompareTo(League other)
    {
        if(other == null)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        return this.ISO.CompareTo(other.ISO);
    }
}
```

I get the same exception on this line:

[image]

seems that the `AsyncObservableCollection` cannot locate the `IComparable` implementation, maybe this should be implemented in `CheckedListItem<T>` instead of `Country`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161895/discussion-between-pivutali-and-mjwills).

Comment: `CheckedListItem` may need to implement `IComparable` also..

Comment: For the record, I don't view this as a duplicate of the post voted for by others, nor did I cast my vote as duplicate. I *did* cast my vote as the question is missing a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. There is both way too much detail in the above, and not enough, because even though you've included a lot of useless information (I assure you, you can reproduce the problem without your special `AsyncObservableCollection`, and likely without much of the rest), you have not included something that can be copy/pasted into a blank project, compiled, and run.

Comment: Please read, in addition to [mcve], the page at [ask], including all of the articles linked at the bottom of that page. Those resources will give you critical information to help you present your question in a clear, answerable way. Take it to heart, be willing to be self-critical and gain insight into how this post and previous ones fail to meet the bar required on Stack Overflow, and you will get the help you need.